# Unexpected results from nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

So I'm taking a course on edx and doing an exercise on nested loops
and I'm having a really difficult time trying to understand how I'm getting the wrong answer.

Here is the exercise

```
m = 0
for x in range (1,3):
    k = 0
    for y in range (-2,0):
        k = k + y
        m = m + k
print (m)
```

I know when there's a nested loop the first for loop will iterate once then proceed to the second for loop and that will iterate to completion so with that knowledge I began to do the math:

```
0+-2      k=-2
0+-2      m=-2

-2+-1     k=-3
-2+-3     m=-5

-3+-2     k=-5
-5+-2     m=-7

0+-1      k=-1
-7+-1     m=-16
```

I end up with -16

Comment: Why not just print out `m` and `k` each time through the loop to debug.

Comment: The key line for your confusion is `k=0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resetting `k` to 0 for each iteration of `x`. Your calculations assume that `k` is not reset.

You can see this by printing out intermediary values for `k` and `m`:

```
m = 0
for x in range (1,3):
    k = 0
    for y in range (-2,0):
        k = k + y
        m = m + k
        print(k, m)

# -2 -2
# -3 -5
# -2 -7
# -3 -10
```

Comment: Why does k reset and m doesnt? Does it have to do with scope?

Comment: Because you set `k=0` beneath the line `for x in range(1, 3)`. While `m=0` is defined above that line.